# Yii2 - swap ListView for GridView on jQuery.click()

Tags: jquery, yii2

I have a ListView, which I create myself. And I have a GridView, using `kartik\grid\GridView`.

Both work fine on their corresponding pages. They use the same parameters, such as `$dataProvider` and `$searchModel`.

```
<div id="grid">
    <?= GridView::widget([....]); ?>
</div>
```

And

```
<div id="list">
    <?= ListView::widget([....]); ?>
</div>
```

The problem is, when I put them on the same page, the second one loses its interactivity - things like pagination, for example. I have a jQuery.click() button to swap out the GridView for the ListView but it doesn't work.

```
$("#presentation-switcher").click(function() {
    $("#data-view").load("_list.php");
});
```

I've experimented with different ids, different dataprovides etc. but to no avail. Perhaps I am taking the wrong approach? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a new page of item view like `_list_item`:

```
<?= 
ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $listDataProvider,
    'options' => [
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'list-wrapper',
        'id' => 'list-wrapper',
    ],
    'layout' => "{pager}\n{items}\n{summary}",
    'itemView' => '_list_item',
]);
?>
```

[More Detail](http://www.codevoila.com/post/4/yii2-listview-example)

Comment: Obviously it follows, that I needed to use a `$gridDataProvider` too for the `GridView`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to put GridView and ListView widgets inside Pjax, such as:

```
\yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(); 
      echo GridView::widget([
      ]); 
\yii\widgets\Pjax::end();
```

and

```
\yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(); 
      echo ListView::widget([
      ]); 
\yii\widgets\Pjax::end();
```

Comment: Using Chrome Developers tools, I get a completely blank console - no errors at all.

Comment: So, what are errors/problem that you have using both widgets (listview and gridview together) ?

Comment: I have no pagination buttons in whichever of the two come second in the file.

Comment: This is strange because pagination buttons are html and not created runtime (es. using javascript).

Comment: Does it happen with Yii 2 default GridView as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

In the `GridView` set `showFooter` as `false`:

```
'panel' => [
    'showFooter' => false,
    //Other settings you may wan

    'heading' => '<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="iconLeft fa fa-th-list"></i> '.Yii::t('app/buttons', 'list').' '.$title.'</h3>',
    'type' => 'success',
    //'before' => Html::a('<i class="iconLeft fa fa-plus"></i> '.Yii::t('app/buttons', 'create'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']),
    //'after' => Html::a('<i class="iconLeft fa fa-repeat"></i> '.Yii::t('app/buttons', 'reset_grid'), ['index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info']),
],
```

And then add pager options explicitly:

```
'pager' => [
    'options' => ['class' => 'pagination'],   // set class name used in ui list of pagination
    'prevPageLabel' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',   // Set the label for the "previous" page button
    'nextPageLabel' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',   // Set the label for the "next" page button
    'firstPageLabel' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>',   // Set the label for the "first" page button
    'lastPageLabel' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>',    // Set the label for the "last" page button
    'nextPageCssClass' => 'next',    // Set CSS class for the "next" page button
    'prevPageCssClass' => 'prev',    // Set CSS class for the "previous" page button
    'firstPageCssClass' => 'first',    // Set CSS class for the "first" page button
    'lastPageCssClass' => 'last',    // Set CSS class for the "last" page button
    'maxButtonCount' => 10,    // Set maximum number of page buttons that can be displayed
],
```

Also you don't have to set `\yii\widgets\Pjax::begin();` and `\yii\widgets\Pjax::end();` because `kartik\grid\GridView` uses `Pjax` as default.